# Probability for tickets in a raffle

Tags: probability

I have been stuck on this problem for hours and I would greatly appreciate your help.

A lottery contains 100 tickets and David buys two. Keen to win he subsequently buys another three tickets. If there are 3 prizes, determine his chances of winning exactly 2 prizes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cant you just say that David has 5 tickets?

Comment: Yes, you could. I just wrote down the question exactly how it was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to buy $2$ out of $3$ good tickets and $3$ out of $97$ bad tickets is:

$$\binom{3}{2}\cdot\binom{97}{3}=442320$$

---

The number of ways to buy $5$ out of $100$ tickets is:

$$\binom{100}{5}=75287520$$

---

So the probability of winning exactly $2$ prizes is:

$$\frac{442320}{75287520}=\frac{19}{3234}$$

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how you got the (3/2) * (97/3)

Comment: @Charlie: You're welcome. Please see updated answer with explanations...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Charlie: You're welcome :) Please make sure that this answer is correct, as I see a different answer here which was up-voted, so obviously at least one of these two answers is wrong.

Comment: @barakmanos:  Your answer is correct and mine is not because my solution assumes that the probability of winning is independent for each ticket, which is not true. Too bad, because my incorrect solution gave David a better chance to win twice!  I've went ahead and deleted my erroneous solution.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: Gotcha, thanks.